# Display html table from php using ajax or jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, xml

So I have an SQL database and table, and a php file calls the 10 results from it like this.

```
<?php

    $servername = getenv('IP');
    $username = getenv('C9_USER');
    $password = "";
    $database = "c9";
    $dbport = 3306;

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

    if (!$con) {
        die("Error! Check your internet connection and try again!");
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con, "users");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    echo "<table>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Village</th>
    <th>Power</th>
    <th>Influence</th>
    <th>Economy</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['village'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['power'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['influence'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['economy'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

This is an JQuery ajax script I made but it doesn't seem to work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if(xmlhttp==null){
   alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
   return false;
  }
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      //document.getElementById("divTable").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
   }
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/server.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);


});

return false;
```

What would be the best way to display this table from the php file on a separate index.html file. AJAX, JQuery AJAX, and XML are all options but I don't know how I would do this.

I ideally would want to display the result from the PHP file with `document.getElementById('leaderboard').innerHTML` because it would take all the html code, including the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it!
In Ajax code:
`var dataString = 'ajax=true';
   $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/server.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){

                alert(data);

            }
        });`

In PHP code:
`$query = "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 10";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    echo json_encode($result); exit();`

Comment: to use this ajax code you need to attach the jquery file.